# [IOS SDK]- touchesBegan with specific object?

Tags: xcode, ios4, touchesbegan, nsset, touchesmoved

When I touch anywhere on screen touchesBegan event triggered. but I couldn't manage how if I touch specific object as like UIImageView?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];

 imageView.center = location;

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, found the solution, here is the code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == imageView) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

        imageView.center = location;

    }

}
```